# Как сделать фильтр по нажатию кнопки Django?

Tags: python-3.x, html5, django, шаблоны, django-filter

Доброго времени суток!

Столкнулся с проблемой, вернее будет сказать, незнанием, как реализовать следующую структуру:

На сайте, первоначально отрисовываются лишь кнопки видов техники (компьютеры, смартфоны, планшеты), по нажатию на одну из кнопок должны отрисовываться следующие кнопки (либо модели компьютеров, либо модели телефоном, либо модели планшетов), ну и далее, соответственно всё происходит так же, в зависимости от глубины вложенности моделей.

Поскольку, мог объяснить сумбурно, вот uml-схема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что имею на данный момент:

- Использование библиотеки Django-filters
- Структуру моделей

Не рабочий код, который у меня сейчас:

*models.py*:

```
from django.db import models


class Tech(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название техники' ,max_length=225)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вид техники'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Виды техники'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Firm(models.Model):
    tech = models.ForeignKey(Tech, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Вид техники')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название фирмы', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фирма производитель'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фирмы производители'

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Техника: {}, Фирма: {}'.format(self.tech, self.name))


class ModelTech(models.Model):
    tech = models.ForeignKey(Tech, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Вид техники')
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Фирма производитель')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Название модели', max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Модели техники'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Модели техники'

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Техника: {}, Фирма: {}, Модель: {}'.format(self.tech,self.firm ,self.name))


class Fix(models.Model):
    tech = models.ForeignKey(Tech, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Вид техники')
    firm = models.ForeignKey(Firm, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Фирма производитель')
    model_tech = models.ForeignKey(ModelTech, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Модель')
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name='Вид ремонта', max_length=255)
    price = models.FloatField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Вид ремонта'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Виды ремонта'

    def __str__(self):
        return ('Техника: {}, Фирма: {}, Модель: {}, Ремонт: {}, Цена: {}'.format(self.tech, self.firm,
                self.model_tech ,self.name, self.price))
```

*filters.py*:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
import django_filters
from .models import *


class FirmFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    tech = django_filters.ModelMultipleChoiceFilter(queryset=Tech.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Firm
        fields = ['tech']
```

*views.py*:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Tech, Firm, ModelTech, Fix


def index(request):
    return render(request, 'index/index.html')
```

*urls.py*:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', views.index),
]
```

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="get">
    {% for tech in firm_list %}
      <button type="submit" class="button" name="tech" value="{{ tech }}">
        {{ tech }}
      </button>
    {% endfor %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```